# OS X Mountain Lion - See unread notification badge in menu bar or Notification Center icon

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, notifications

Is there a way to show a badge or to highlight the notification center icon where there are unread notifications? A program, an app, anything that do this! A badge on the Notification Center icon or make the icon color change, something like this.
Thank you

Comment: This question would fit best at http://apple.stackexchange.com/